# Facebook desktop login OAuth2 ( redirect to localhost ) issue

Tags: facebook, qt, oauth-2.0

I'm using O2 Qt/C++ lib (advised on http://oauth.net/2/ ) to log in to my application using Facebook, Google+, etc. accounts from default browser. For some reason Facebook stopped working some time ago. I'm getting (sorry, can't paste images):

```
Facebook Login

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Email or Phone: ________
Password: _________
```

if i'm NOT logged in to Facebook. If I'm already logged in to Facebook in my default browser everything is ok.

URL is: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=token&client_id=my_application_id&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:some_port_1/&scope=email`

I'm aware of OAuth settings in Advanced tab, I even added several additional items there:

```
Client OAuth Login - YES
Embedded browser OAuth Login - YES
Valid OAuth redirect URIs
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
https://my.some_site_1.com/oauth/facebook 
https://my.some_site_2.com/oauth/facebook 
http://127.0.0.1/ 
http://127.0.0.1:some_port_1/ 
https://my.some_site_1.com/oauth/facebook/ 
https://my.some_site_2.com/oauth/facebook/
```

Still w/o any success.

Did Facebook restrict 127.0.0.1 redirect_uri at all or I am missing something important? Do I need any additional redirect URI there?

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1". I change it in "Site" section in Facebook OAuth settings as well as in C++ defines in OAuth library itself and it worked.